# How to force specific order of the variables on the X axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2

My question has to do with order of plot bars when using ggplot.

```
EffectNames = c("Pull Back(A)","Hook(B)","Peg(C)","AB","BC","AC","ABC")
Half_Effect = c(10.4, 6.5, 5.6, 1.6, 0.98, .77, .65)
paretoData = cbind(EffectNames, Half_Effect)
paretoData = as.data.frame(paretoData)

ggplot(paretoData, aes(x = EffectNames, y = Half_Effect)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    geom_text(aes(label = Half_Effect), vjust = 1.5, colour = "white")
```

Result:
Bar heights are in following order

```
1.6 0.65 0.77 0.98    6.5    5.6        10.4
 AB  ABC   AC   BC Hook(B) Peg(C) PullBack(A)
```

Bar heights are not in order seen in Half_Effect. How to force ordering of EffectNames to match descending order of Half_Effect? Can this be done in ggplot2?  Yes it can! See solution below.

```
EffectNames=c( "Pull Back(A)","Hook(B)", "Peg(C)","AB", "BC", "AC", "ABC")
Half_Effect=c( 10.4,6.5,5.6,1.6,0.98,.77,.65 )
paretoData=data.frame(EffectNames, Half_Effect)
paretoData
paretoData$EffectNames = factor(paretoData$EffectNames, 
    levels=c("Pull Back(A)","Hook(B)", "Peg(C)","AB", "BC", "AC", "ABC"))
p=ggplot(paretoData, aes(x=EffectNames, y=Half_Effect)) +
geom_bar(stat="identity") +
geom_text(aes(label=Half_Effect), vjust=1.5, colour="white")
p
```

Comment: Effect is factor type, you can convert it to numeric first

Comment: You can just do `paretoData=data.frame(EffectNames, Effect)` and skip the `cbind` step.

Comment: Two options here: If you want the data plotted in the numerical order of `Effect`, you can do `ggplot(paretoData, aes(x=reorder(EffectNames, Effect), y=Effect))`. For an arbitrary order of `EffectNames`, after you create your data frame, set the factor levels in the order you want. For example, `paretoData$EffectNames = factor(paretoData$EffectNames, levels=c("AB","AC","Hook(B)", etc.))`. Then run your original plot code.

Comment: The two suggestions made a difference. Thank you. Mary A. Marion

Answer (score 48):

Elaborating [eipi10's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40199274/r-ggplot-how-to-force-specific-order-of-the-variables-on-the-x-axis/41417136#comment67664521_40199274), the reordering of levels can by accomplished conveniently using Hadley's `forcats` package. In addition, the reordering can be done within the call to `aes()` instead of manipulating the underlying data. This offers additional flexibilty in finding a suitable graphical display.

### Initial plot

```
paretoData <-  data.frame(
  EffectNames = c("Pull Back(A)", "Hook(B)", "Peg(C)", "AB", "BC", "AC", "ABC"), 
  Half_Effect = c(10.4, 6.5, 5.6, 1.6, 0.98, .77, .65))

library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(paretoData, aes(x = EffectNames, y = Half_Effect)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label = Half_Effect), vjust = 1.5, colour = "white")
p
```

[image]

Here, the order is alphabetical by default.

### Reorder the levels in order of first appearance

```
library(forcats)
p + aes(x = fct_inorder(EffectNames))
```

[image]

- The factors are ordered by their first appearance in the vector (which probably was choosen intentionally by the OP with respect to the value of `Half_Effect`, so no real surprise here.)
- In this example, `fct_inorder()` saves us from typing the same stuff twice which would be required when explicitely specifying the levels in a call to `factor`.
- The plot `p` was modified by only changing the `x` aesthetics. The underlying data needn't to be touched.

### Reorder the levels according to another variable

```
p + aes(x = fct_reorder(EffectNames, Half_Effect))
```

[image]

Here, the levels are ordered by increasing value of `Half_Effect`. We could have achieved the same effect by using `reorder()` from base R instead of `fct_reorder()`.

To show the levels **in decreasing order as requested by the OP** we can do

```
p + aes(x = fct_reorder(EffectNames, Half_Effect, .desc = TRUE))
```

[image]

Note that `reorder()` has *no* explicit parameter to reverse the order so we would need to modify the controlling variable `reorder(EffectNames, -Half_Effect)`.

Comment: Alternatively, one can use `scale_x_discrete`.

Comment: ok but how to avoid the "fct_inorder" appearing in the label ?

Comment: @Digao You can just use `labs` to change the axis titles.