# How to do side by side bar chart ggplot and retain original sorting

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

Thanks in advance for your help. I have been searching stack overflow and google with this issue and have not been successful.

I need a side by side horizontal bar chart of the word and its frequency in two files.

My data frame is as below:

```
   head(comp,10)
              WORD FREQ RDFREQ
   170     project   67      5
   20     business   64     14
   117  management   53     13
   59  development   34      4
   211     support   27      6
   215     systems   25     10
   102 information   22      2
   201    software   21      6
   203   solutions   20      2
   220   technical   20      2
```

I have used melt to create the frequency frame as below:

```
   dfp1 &lt;- melt(comp, value.factor = TRUE) 
   head(dfp1,20)
              WORD variable value
   1       project     FREQ    67
   2      business     FREQ    64
   3    management     FREQ    53
   4   development     FREQ    34
   5       support     FREQ    27
   6       systems     FREQ    25
   7   information     FREQ    22
   8      software     FREQ    21
   9     solutions     FREQ    20
   10    technical     FREQ    20
   11 applications     FREQ    19
   12     planning     FREQ    18
```

My code to plot is

```
   g &lt;- ggplot(dfp1, aes(x = WORD, y= value, order=-   as.integer(value)))
   g &lt;- g + geom_bar(aes(fill = variable), position = "dodge", stat="identity")
   g &lt;- g + coord_flip() 
   g &lt;- g + theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size=12))
   g &lt;- g + labs(x = "Keyword", y = "Count", 
              title = paste("File1 vs File2")
              )
   print(g)
```

The plot that I get is sorted by the WORD instead of the descending order of frequency. Thanks again and looking forward to the responses.

Comment: Package *forcats* functions can be useful here.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41417136/2461552)

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot @aosmith.

Answer (score 0):

would this work for you,

```
comp <- structure(list(WORD = structure(c(5L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 8L, 9L, 3L, 
6L, 7L, 10L), .Label = c("business", "development", "information", 
"management", "project", "software", "solutions", "support", 
"systems", "technical"), class = "factor"), FREQ = c(67L, 64L, 
53L, 34L, 27L, 25L, 22L, 21L, 20L, 20L), RDFREQ = c(5L, 14L, 
13L, 4L, 6L, 10L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 2L)), .Names = c("WORD", "FREQ", 
"RDFREQ"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("170", "20", "117", 
"59", "211", "215", "102", "201", "203", "220"))


comp %>% gather(variable, Count, -WORD) %>% 
         mutate(Keyword = fct_reorder(WORD, Count, .desc = FALSE)) %>% 
           ggplot(aes(x = Keyword, y = Count, fill = variable)) + 
           geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = "dodge") + coord_flip() +  
             theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size=12)) +  
             labs(title = paste("File1 vs File2") )
```

[image: ordered geom_bar]

if you want to order exclusively on `FREQ` you could do something like this,

```
comp %>% arrange(desc(FREQ)) %>% mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
         gather(variable, Count, -WORD, -id) %>%              
         mutate(Keyword = fct_reorder(WORD, id, .desc = TRUE)) %>%
          ggplot(aes(x = Keyword, y = Count, fill = variable)) +
          geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = "dodge") + coord_flip() +
          theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size=12))
          + labs(title = paste("File1 vs File2") )
```

[image]