# ggplot: re-order categorical y-axis (Gantt chart)

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I am trying to produce a Gantt chart out of a table with different task (each having a start date and end date).

```
library(tidyverse)

# Sample data
df1 <- data.frame(from = c("2020-01-01", "2020-02-02", "2020-05-04", "2020-02-01", "2020-01-20", "2020-02-10"),
                  to =   c("2020-03-30", "2020-03-15", "2020-05-20", "2020-04-05", "2020-03-05", "2020-04-13"),
                  task= c("Task 1", "Task 2", "Task 3", "Task 4", "Task 5", "Task 6"),
                  group = c("Finance", "Finance", "Research", "Research", "Other", "Other")
)

# Plot gantt-chart
df1 %>% mutate(from = as.Date(from),
               to = as.Date(to)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c(from, to), values_to = "date") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=date, y=task, colour = group)) + 
  geom_line(lwd=3) +
  geom_point(aes(color=group), alpha=.5, pch=18, size=5) +
  scale_x_date(position="bottom", date_breaks = "1 week", date_labels="%U") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  ggtitle("Milestones") +
  labs(y="", x = "", colour="Responsible")
```

So far so good, but now I have a major problem and a minor problem:

major problem:

- How can I re-order the categories on the y-axis as they appear in the data (not alphabetically)? From top to bottom it should be: Finance, Research, Other. Additionally, within each category (finance, research, other) the lines should be ordered by starting date (i.e. the task starting first should be on top)

minor problem:

- on the x-axis how can I plot a thicker line for each month and a thinner line for each week?

Thanks for help!

Comment: 1) `library(tidyverse)` also loads `ggplot2`, the explicit load is not needed; 2) to order an axis by a categorical variable, define it as a factor with the required levels order, ggplot will keep to that order, see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40199274/how-to-force-specific-order-of-the-variables-on-the-x-axis).

Answer (score 4):

This could be achieved like so:

1. As @RuiBarrades mentioned in his comments to get the right order you have to convert to a factor and set the levels in the right order. First, set the levels for the groups. Second, to get the tasks in the desired order I rearrange the dataset by group and start date and make use of `forcats::fct_inorder` to set the levels of the tasks in the desired order.
2. If I got you right you want different grid lines for week and month? This could be achieved by setting `date_breaks_minor="month"` and styling of the grid lines via `theme` and `panel.grid.minor/major.x`. Here I opted for a "black" color but if you prefer different sizes you could do so via `size`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

# Sample data
df1 <- data.frame(from = c("2020-01-01", "2020-02-02", "2020-05-04", "2020-02-01", "2020-01-20", "2020-02-10"),
                  to =   c("2020-03-30", "2020-03-15", "2020-05-20", "2020-04-05", "2020-03-05", "2020-04-13"),
                  task= c("Task 1", "Task 2", "Task 3", "Task 4", "Task 5", "Task 6"),
                  group = c("Finance", "Finance", "Research", "Research", "Other", "Other")
)

# Plot gantt-chart
df1 %>% mutate(from = as.Date(from),
               to = as.Date(to),
               group = factor(group, levels = c("Finance", "Research", "Other"))) %>%
  arrange(desc(group), desc(from)) %>% 
  mutate(task = forcats::fct_inorder(task)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c(from, to), values_to = "date") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=date, y=task, colour = group)) + 
  geom_line(lwd=3) +
  geom_point(aes(color=group), alpha=.5, pch=18, size=5) +
  scale_x_date(position="bottom", date_breaks = "1 week", date_minor_breaks = "1 month",
               date_labels="%U") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), 
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_line(color = "black"))+
  ggtitle("Milestones") +
  labs(y="", x = "", colour="Responsible")
```

[image]

Comment: Great tip on the "forcats::fct_inorder(task)" part. Much better at scale than using the same method as for Group/Responsible given potential scope. 

OP - If you are making multiple graphics/items from the data frame take the forward pipe (%>%) out of the graph call and just over-write the df group column with itself as a factor version.

Comment: Wow, that's great! Thanks very much. Just a follow-up question: Why are the lines of months not exactly on the ticks of the weeks?

Comment: That's because in general weeks don't start a the start of a month and of course because a month is approx. equal to around 4.33 weeks.

Comment: ... but you could try `scale_x_date(position="bottom", date_breaks = "4 weeks", date_minor_breaks = "1 week"` and use `panel.grid.major.x = element_line(color = "black")` instead of `panel.grid.minor.x` which instead of a month uses periods of 4 weeks.