# How to reorder numbers+string used as ticker in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyverse

I have tried to reorder my x axis tickers so they follow like: DQQ1, DQQ2, DQQ3 and etc. but I couldn't find the solution. Does anybody have an idea about how to deal with this problem. Thank you.

my code:

```
d %>%
  filter(ISO3 == "SLE") %>%
  select(starts_with("DQQ"), YEAR_WAVE) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("DQQ"), names_to = "DQQ", values_to = "Value") %>%
  filter(Value == 1) %>%
  mutate(DQQ = as.factor(DQQ)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(fct_relevel(DQQ, sort), fill = as.factor(YEAR_WAVE))) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge") +
  labs(
    title = "DQQ YES Answer Counts",
    subtitle = "Counts of 'Yes' answers to DQQ indicators for Sierra Leone",
    fill = "Year",
       ) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(add = c(0, 200))) +
  theme(
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    axis.line.x = element_blank(),
    axis.line.y = element_blank(),
    plot.margin = unit(c(0, .5, 0, 0), "cm"),
    axis.ticks.length = unit(0, "cm"),
    #aspect.ratio = 0.5,
    legend.position = c(0.75, .95),
    legend.justification = c("right", "top"),
    legend.box.just = "right",
    legend.margin = margin(6, 6, 6, 6),
    axis.title.y = element_text(color = "#993333", size = 14, face = "bold"),
    axis.title.x = element_blank(),
    axis.text.x = element_text(face="bold", color="#993333", size = 12, angle=90, hjust = 0.1, vjust = 0.5)
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to force specific order of the variables on the X axis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40199274/how-to-force-specific-order-of-the-variables-on-the-x-axis)

Comment: Not actually, because my question invovled combination of numbers and string for sorting. But thanks for referring that post I learned from that too.

Comment: Try using `gtools::mixedsort()` to sort alphanumeric strings

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by:

1. Using `stringr::str_extract()` to extract the relevant numbers.
2. Using `forcats::fct_reorder()` to reorder your variable according to its rank

Here is  a toy example:

```r
library(tibble) # for tribble()
library(dplyr)
library(stringr) # for str_extract()
library(forcats) # for fct_reorder()
library(ggplot2)

dummy <- 
  tribble(
    ~id,       ~value,
    "DQQ13",    10,
    "DQQ10",    8,
    "DQQ05",    13,
    "DQQ22_03", 7,
    "DQQ22_01", 11
  )

head(dummy)
#> # A tibble: 5 × 2
#>   id       value
#>   <chr>    <dbl>
#> 1 DQQ13       10
#> 2 DQQ10        8
#> 3 DQQ05       13
#> 4 DQQ22_03     7
#> 5 DQQ22_01    11

# convert to ordered factor
dummy <- mutate(dummy, id = ordered(id))

# make numerical rank variable by extracting first number
# from string
dummy <- mutate(dummy, 
                rank = str_extract(id, "\\d+") |> 
                  as.numeric())

# reorder using ranking variabel
dummy <- mutate(dummy, fct_reorder(id, rank))

# Check it's worked
levels(dummy[["id"]])
#> [1] "DQQ05"    "DQQ10"    "DQQ13"    "DQQ22_01" "DQQ22_03"

# Plot
ggplot(dummy, aes(x = id, y = value)) + 
  geom_col(fill = "cyan3", col = "black") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-06-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: So ggplot use level as a sort in axis and we need to sort the level and then plot a factor variable ? right?

Comment: Yes, ggplot uses factor levels to determine the order that axis are plotted in

Answer (score 0):

By default the factor orders based on the string. In order to give the result that you want, you have to order it by the number (not the string). You can reorder of the x axis with below code and give to the x axis on aes():

```
d <- c("DQQ1", "DQQ10", "DQQ17", "DQQ2")
factor(d, levels = d[order(as.numeric(str_extract(d, "\\d+")))])
```

Comment: Thanks, but how I could use the factor level as a variable in my ggplot?

Comment: just put it inside the ggplot. 

ggplot(aes(x=factor(<column name>, levels = d[order(as.numeric(str_extract(d, "\\d+")))])))